# isolated scope directive doesnt react to change : angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

i have created a directive

```
adocsModule.directive('modalFooter', function (globalService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            'onSave': '&',
            'onClose': '&',
            'loading': '='
        },
        template: '<div class="modal-footer">' +
                 ' <div class="pull-right">' +
                 '<button type="submit" ui-ladda="loading" class="button-save ladda-button" ng-click="onSave()" data-style="expand-right">' +
                 '<span class="ladda-label">{{saveText}}</span>' +
                 '</button>' +
                 ' <button class="button-cancel" ng-click="onClose()">{{cancelText}}</button>' +
                 ' </div> </div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

            scope.saveText = attrs.savetext;
            scope.cancelText = attrs.canceltext;
        }
    };
});
```

to use this

```
<modal-footer loading="administrator.loading" on-save="administrator.save()" on-close="administrator.cancel()"></modal-footer>
```

in my controller when i press save i do . administrator.loading = true it shows loading icon but when  on callback i do administrator.loading = false  it doesnt stop loading icon. it means it doesnt react to change

i have tried to use scope.$watch and attrs.$observe but problem with those it start showing loading icon on start and it doesnt get back in watch :S

```
Module.controller('AdminstratorController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
administrator.save = function () {                   
                        administrator.loading = true;
                        var callback = function () { 
                           administrator.loading  false;                           
                        }

                            setTimeout(function () {
                                administratorService.updateAdministrator( callback);
                            }, 1000);

                };
}]);
```

can some one guide me how can i fix it.

Comment: You need to pass in form.$valid and administrator from the modalFooter?

Comment: i m passing controller property administrator.loading = true that i set to false when i get ajax result so this property gets changed in controller but my directive doesnt see the change and doesnt react to it even i have used attrs.$observe

Comment: Where is your ajax and place where you are setting it to false? Also when you click on `save`(`ng-click="onSave()"`) Do you see your controllers `save` function not getting any arguments?

Comment: but you sure what at the first time when your directive works you getting `loading` value ?

Comment: You need to use `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout`. `('AdminstratorController', ['$scope','$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {` and `$timeout(function () {administratorService.updateAdministrator(callback);}, 1000);` When you update something inside `setTimeout` angular does not know about it until the next digest cycle happens. If you use `$timeout`digest cycle will happen. Also how does your ajax call look like and why do you need a timeout with 1sec?Are you not using `$http` ?

Comment: @PSL it works thanku .. can u put it as answer so i can accept . it was so stupid of me as i was using setTimeout but thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue could be the `setTimeout`, you are updating a scope variable inside setTimeout, it will not trigger digest cycle so you will not see the update until the next digest cycle happens. Wrap your call within the angular version of timeout, i.e `$timeout`, using that will trigger the digest cycle after the timeout it done.

```
    Module.controller('AdminstratorController', ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {
       administrator.save = function () {                   
            administrator.loading = true;
            var callback = function () { 
              administrator.loading  false;                           
            }

            $timeout(function () {
               administratorService.updateAdministrator( callback);
            });

        };
    }]);
```

On a side note i am not sure what you are passing around callbacks and using a timeout, if you make use of promises and return an (angular)promise from your `updateAdministrator` you can chain through them and update your scope variable there and you will no longer need to wrap it in timeout at all.

Comment: it was just for testing purpose i have use promises and for ajax i have defined other service and call back called when promised get resolved . thanks for helping me out

Comment: Sure. You could instead do `administratorService.updateAdministrator().then(callback)` you should be good. :)